# Scala - mixing of packages and variables?

Tags: scala

A very strange thing indeed. I have the following project structure:

```
myproject/one/two
```

Inside package `myproject` I have a class:

```
abstract class A (two: Buffer[Int])
```

and then, inside package `one` I have:

```
object B extends A (Buffer[Int](1, 2, 3)) {

  val с = two.map(_ + 1)  // ERROR

}
```

However, the erros says:

> object `map` is not a member of package
>   `myproject/one/two`

which is obviously erroneous because it should be perfectly clear that I don't refer to the packages here, but to the local variable... And `two` also is not shown in context-assist after `this.` in `B`, but is shown in `A` (Scala-IDE). Is this an intended behavior and I am doing something wrong or is it a bug?

**UPDATE:**

(simultaneously suggested by Nicolas :D ) Been able to resolve the name collision by specifying `two` as `val` (making it public). I did not notice at first, but it was private and unavailable in the successor class. Nevertheless I am still wondering, why and how did Scala pick up a package instead of saying that the variable does not exist or is not accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not as clear as you might think. Without a modifier, two is private to abstract class A class `A`. Thus your declaration of `a` is equivalent to `abstract class A (private[this] A)`. It means that field `two` can't be seen from object `B`. A direct consequence is that the compiler look into the only defiition of `two` visible from `B`: the package `two`.

Comment: I just don't know - so it is ok for the compiler to use packages like variables in the source code?

Comment: It doesn't use package as a variable. It just try to figure out what two might be. And the only two it has in its scope is a package.

Comment: Said differently: As your statement is invalid, how could the compiler understand that you need a variable here and not a package?

Comment: Oh, I got it. This facility thinks that I might do something like `java.io.File` where packages serve as a part of class file name. Because if I say just `val с = two`, the error is `package two is not a value` - which, to me, is just not as explicit as it should be...

Comment: I know but unfortunately... It's as unclear as your goal is for the compiler. ;)